# Freemarker - how to access a null key in a map?

Tags: hash, null, key, freemarker

In Freemarker, I have a `Map` that contains `null` as a key.
How can I reach that entry?

As far as I know, Freemarker doesn't know the concept of null, so there's nothing like `map[null]`, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, also `map[key]` only works with string keys (in 2.3.x at least). Try `map?api.get(null)` (where `null` is really just a variable that doesn't exist).